# AVD Manager device's screen starts with small resolution/zoom

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, windows-server, android-virtual-device

So I'm running an android emulator using android's sdk AVD Manager on an AWS EC2 instance(I have to use ARM system images for the emulator since hardware virtualization is not supported in EC2 instances) and I can't figure out why but when I start a device the screen kinda starts in wrong resolution/"Zoom in" mode:

[image]

Thats the device configuration:

[image]

I tried to change the scaling part when starting the emulator but it seems like it's not effecting anything and I get a warning that says:

*"The -scale flag is obsolete and will be ignored."*

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? or how to reconfigure it to make the screen look normal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same issue and after so many tries i used WXGA720 while selecting skin type. This solved my issue[image]